# How to get the hour and minutes difference between 2 datetimestamp in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have 2 timestamp dates:

1. 2/24/2010  1:05:15 AM
2. 2/25/2010  4:05:17 AM

Can anyone please advise what function should I use in Excel to get the difference in hours and minutes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The difference in hours:

```
=(A2-A1)*24
```

The difference in minutes:

```
=(A2-A1)*24*60
```

The difference in hours and minutes:

```
=TRUNC((A2-A1)*24)      - the hours portion
=MOD((A2-A1)*24*60,60)  - the minutes portion
```

Comment: i found that this will also work: =TEXT(A2-A1,"h:mm") for my case

Comment: Is there a reason you use `=(A2-A1)*24*60` instead of `=(A2-A1)*1440`?

Comment: @Zaider, using '*24*60' is more obvious (to me at least) and therefore more maintainable

Comment: I does not work if there is time in AM-PM e.g.  11:55 AM to 1:20 PM it says 11 Hours :)

Comment: Will this work if the difference exceeds 1 day. Cause I observed the results are messed up in that case.

Comment: Sorry couldnt add a comment to @Tusharshar.
If you want the duration between two dates with timestamp, you can use this: =text(A2-A1,"[h]:mm:ss") - Duration in hours
=text(G14-F14,"[mm]") - Duration in minutes Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

this is straight simple in excel and no need to do anything except applying the time format to the cell.

two easy steps:

1. put the formula: **=B2-A2**
2. simply apply the custom format **"h:mm"** to the cell.

Comment: If the elapsed time may exceed 24 hours you can use custom format dd hh:mm eg result: "01 23:01"  ( 1 day 23 hours and 1 minute)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP100704681033.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Excel is able to handle date and time arithmetic.  It does this by holding the dates and times as decimals.  If you key in a date and time in a format that Excel recognises it will (helpfully!) hold the data as a date and time data type.  The integer bit is days, and the decimal bit is time.  You can use a time cell format to display the time bit in hours minutes seconds etc, or you can convert the decimal to hours, minutes and seconds using 60 in a simple formula

The text formula works by displaying the answer in a time format.

Answer (score 0):

For difference greater than one day some of before answers messes up, better putting up this way for days, hours, minutes & seconds:

```
=INT(B2-A2) & " days, " & HOUR(B2-A2) & " hours, " & MINUTE(B2-A2) & " minutes and " & SECOND(B2-A2) & " seconds"
```

It will output in format like

> 1 days, 3 hours, 0 minutes and 2 seconds

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best option is click on format > custom > [h]:mm, it will work.

01-09-2019 18:55
31-08-2019 03:26

OUTPUT -> 39:26