# How do I get the difference between 2 Oracle custom dateTimeStamp in Excel?

Tags: oracle, excel, excel-formula, timestamp, vba

I have been running an oracle query and have exported the result set to an `Excel` sheet.

The generated Excel sheet contains **2 dateTimeStamp** as **TEXT** cells.

- 07-JUN-16 01.20.05.232458000
- 07-JUN-16 01.20.12.415791000

I need a way to find ***difference in seconds*** between both dateTimeStamp in the **TEXT** cells

Note

I found in the following link an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324897/how-to-get-the-hour-and-minutes-difference-between-2-datetimestamp-in-excel) but for different dateTimeStamp format (2/24/2010 1:05:15 AM)

Comment: do you really need the `.232458000` and `.415791000` portion of the time values? Wouldn't using a format specifier simplify your problem? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter if i dont need mentioned portion ... how i can get diff using `format specifier `

Comment: my recollection is that you can subtract 2 time values directly in excel **once they are in the correct format**. You'll have to experiment both w your Oracle SELECT output and Excel spreadsheet to find a format that will work to time-value subtraction. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I created UDF if you have to do this a lot. It will manipulate the string, then take the difference. Simply format the cell with the right formatting for the value to be displayed as desired. Simply call this function just as you would as a regular excel formula. Date1 is assumed to be the earlier time (smaller).

```
Public Function CustomDateDiff(Date1 As String, Date2 As String) As Date
    Dim newDate1 As Date
    Dim newDate2 As Date

    newDate1 = Replace(Replace(Left(Date1, 18), "-", "/"), ".", ":")
    newDate2 = Replace(Replace(Left(Date2, 18), "-", "/"), ".", ":")

    CustomDateDiff = newDate2 - newDate1
End Function
```