# Date Arithmetic Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, date, math

I'm trying to subtract `Column B` from `Column A` in excel to find out how many hours have passed between these two times but so far no luck.

```
Column A       | Column B 
05/01/11 11:54 | 05/01/11 08:46
```

I appreciate your help

Tried all the TIME related functions and did lots of research online but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula should do what you want:

```
INT(A2-B2)&" days "&TEXT(A2-B2,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hour` function

```
Hour(B1-A1)
```

which gives `3`

Here is a link to another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2324935/4293532

Note: Make sure that your data are formatted as dates, they are generally aligned to the right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in hours rather than days and hours

```
=(A1-B1)*24
```

(which can be rounded down if you want whole hours)